# Cross Site Related Posts?

Tags: tags

This seems like a serious reach but it's something that would help me loads, so currently I have this structure to return the related posts for my music website, and it works flawlessly for returning the results for one website.

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
$first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  's' => $loopartist,
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
  'posts_per_page'=>8,
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

Then some content to display blocks would be returned here, and followed by a standard closing with.

```
endwhile;
} wp_reset_query();
}
```

Now like I said, the above works for my singular website.. but how could I make it so that I could also collect the posts for a website on the same server, with the same design, and the same IP address return related posts as well?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pull data from another site is by using the [Rest API](https://v2.wp-api.org/). The interface is not as powerful as `WP_Query` in terms of the [arguments you can pass](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) to the query, but you can still do something like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://example.com/wp/v2/wp-json/posts?tags=11&per_page=5');
$posts = json_decode($json);
```

The `$posts` variable now contains maximum five post objects with from tag with ID 11, which you can loop through in the normal way (assuming you are using WP 4.7 or higher).